# Box IOS SDK V2 search functionality

Tags: box-api

I am trying to perform search in Box using their IOS SDK V2. Can any one point me out to the right call in the SDK? 
I looked everywhere and all I can see is to perform this using REST and not via their SDk.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: Box IOS SDK Version 2

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the Box iOS SDK. Unfortunately, search is not included in the SDK at this time (Nov 2013). However, it should be fairly easy to add an additional endpoint to the SDK and we gladly accept pull requests. :)

EDIT (Nov 21, 2013): We've just cut a new release that has search. Available here: https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2/releases/tag/v1.2.0. CocoaPods podspec is in the process of being updated.

Comment: Thanks for the input. BTW ,What do you mean by pull request?

Comment: We host the SDK code on GitHub. Pull requests are github's method of collaborating on code.

Comment: I've edited the original post to reflect that we've released a new version that has Search support.